# How to implement a loop according to row number

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I need to change the color of some word for each row Table 
I have a table for wordInput that's mean contains the word that I need to color them and the second Table contain Titles that I need to color some words for it.

My script work when the number of row title equal to the number of
    the row wordInput and That's wrong! because sometimes I have only 1
    row as an input. I need to find solution to how can do the loop for
    each row Title  I got errors evaluating script  when I need to
    change the color of the second-row Title

> TypeError: Cannot call method "split" of null (#4)

this error because now we ARE in the second Row InputWords and it NULL without Value

```js
var row = {
  "Title": ["This reference is to serve as a useful","Title2","Title3"],"wordInput":["serve"] }
//Title contains 3 rows : as string Values
//wordInput contains words that i need to color them in Title :As a string Value
var words = row["wordInput"];// this contain only 1 row ["serve"]
var orgTitle = row["Title"];

words.split(" ").forEach(function (word) {
  orgTitle = orgTitle.replace(new RegExp(word, "g"),'<span style="color: red;">'+word+'</span>');
});


orgTitle;
```

I'm looking for your help thanks

Comment: wordInput is not there in the row

Comment: your snippet is broken

Comment: when you debug, what is the value of the words variable after assigning row["wordInput"]? The error indicates that the row variable does not have a "wordInput" property and so when you try to run split() against it, it throws the error.

Comment: `row["wordInput"]` is `null`

Comment: my  row["wordInput"] its not null I just forget to write the row .. but it contains only one row

Comment: @CristianS. yes, i know it broke when there no word input in the second row. and this is my problem

Comment: Sorry but your explanation has less sense than your question (code). Rephrase and please clean up your snippet. What the check is : `orgTitle;": `

Comment: @CristianS.  I have some problem with this script I have string array of word and I want to use the value that array as an input to color my paragraph could you help me for that this is the LINK https://jsfiddle.net/MokiNex/wncafj5f/39/

Comment: @CristianS. this script o have just a simple words input as string  https://jsfiddle.net/MokiNex/wncafj5f/27/  I want to change this script if I have a an array of string as a words Input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `row.title` is the array that contains all the words that should be highlighted, this is what you need.

```js
var row = {
  "Abstract": "This reference is to serve as a useful reference for testing whether the styling of reference,  works or not. All        occurances of 'reference' should be given a color of red.",
  "Title":["reference" ,"testing"]
};


var wordsToHighlight = row['Title'];
var result = row["Abstract"];

wordsToHighlight.forEach(function (word) {
  result = result.replace(new RegExp(word, "g"),'<span style="color: red;">'+word+'</span>');
});
document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div id="result">
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that what I want exactly.!

Comment: Glad to help. Accept the answer, it would maybe help another one who faces the problem.

Comment: Yes, i will! but there is another condition in this case : https://jsfiddle.net/MokiNex/wncafj5f/44/

Comment: Well, thats another problem. First of all starting from the main idea of how you are storing data. If you store an array of words that should be highlighted, 'reference serve' is definitely inconsistent because there are 2 words. And in the other hand if you persist in saving "phrases" but not single words, you need to change your regular expresion.

Comment: yes i know but sometimes I have two words inside the array for example "Title":["reference serve " ,"testing"] that why I put the split Methode in the last example

Comment: As I said, that would be another problem, hence another question or you go to the magic internet world and search for regEx tools that will make that for you.

Comment: solve it with an array string of wordsToHighlight https://jsfiddle.net/MokiNex/6vtco6fg/5 !Thank you!! now my last step if i have a string array of abstract row like this example https://jsfiddle.net/MokiNex/6vtco6fg/7/  need another loop !?